# View Request Logs on AppEngine Java Dev Server

Tags: google-app-engine

While it is relatively simple to get the app logs on the AppEngine Java Dev server, I haven't been able to find how to get the request logs.  This seems like such a basic feature that there must be an easy way to do it, but so far, I'm stumped.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There is no nice log viewer, logs are directly dumped to server STDOUT, if you use Idea IDE, you will see logs in Application Servers tab at the bottom. Logs are just dumped as they come in (each log.info("logged event"), it is not possible to view logs per request base.